# Why web push not work from iframe in chrome with both load through https?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, web-push

Web push works fine from iframe in local but when i uploaded to cloud server then it does not work in only  chrome or chromium browser.

I have developed a webpush micro-service that serve from a Iframe. That works fine in local but when i uploaded to cloud server then it does not work in only  chrome or chromium browser. You can check from  https:alemran.me (click ^ icon from bot).

Web Worker:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
        return;
    }
    const sendNotification = (title, body ) => {
        return self.registration.showNotification(title,  
            body
         );
    };
   if (event.data) {
        const message = JSON.parse(event.data.text()); 
        event.waitUntil(sendNotification(message.title,message.message));


    }

});

There is no error show in console
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new window with a url and get permission from user....
Like :

```
let win = window.open("your url", "_blank");
 let winInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (win.closed !== false) {  
        window.clearInterval(winInterval );
        //check your api for user subscription status
    }
}, 200);
```